# Custom Post Type, Taxonomy, and Meta Box value, how to sort

Tags: wordpress

I've got a wordpress loop Im working on for a sports website that I'm having an issue with figuring out.

I've created a custom post type called Players
I've created a custom Taxonomy called Position (forward, defense, goalie)
I've also got some custom meta boxes one being jersey number.

I trying to split the page into 3 sections based on position so I've tried to create a query for each loop.  I've written this.

```
$posts = new WP_Query( array( 
'post_type' => 'players', 
'showposts' => 10, 
'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'position', 
        'field' => 'slug', 
        'terms' => 'forward')
                ));
```

The second part of the question I had was if it was possible to arrange this query by a meta box value, I ideally would like to orderby jersey number.

I've tried a few suggestions but in every loop I keep getting all the posts from players.

```
$posts = new WP_Query( array( 
                    'post_type' => 'players', 
                    'showposts' => 10, 
                    'tax_query' => array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'position', 
                                    'field' => 'slug', 
                                    'terms' => 'forward')
                ));
                while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
                    <tr class="player">
                        <td class="leftBrdr"><?php the_title(); ?></td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Figured it out, was using a plugin to create my custom post types and meta boxes. And was missing an extra array in the tax_query.

    $posts = new WP_Query( array( 
      'post_type' => 'players', 
      'showposts' => 10, 
      'orderby' => 'meta_value',
      'meta_key' => 'ecpt_number',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'tax_query' => array( array(
          'taxonomy' => 'position', 
          'field' => 'slug', 
          'terms' => 'forward')
     )));

Answer (score 0):

you can also do order by 'menu order' which is available for pages and your cpt if it is defined as 'hierarchical' => true in the register_post_type.